# R - Write conditional statement based on any value in a vector

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a conditional statement that will check if any value in a vector meets a condition and then writes a result based on that. In the following example, I know c2 has a sum that is much smaller than the other columns, but in my actual data, I don't know which column has the smaller sum. I want to check if any value in the csums vector is less than .1, and if it is, write the column index to a data frame. Furthermore, in some instances there will be two columns below .1, so I need to write both column indexes to the data frame.

```
c1 <- runif(16,.3,.6)
c2 <- c(.01,.01,.01,.01,rep(.00,12))
c3 <- runif(16,.3,.6)
c4 <- runif(16,.3,.6)
c5 <- runif(16,.3,.6)
test.mat1 <- cbind(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)
csums1 <- colSums(test.mat1)
csums1
      c1       c2       c3       c4       c5 
7.279773 0.040000 6.986803 7.200409 6.867637

c6 <- runif(16,.3,.6)
c7 <- runif(16,.3,.6)
c8 <- c(.01,.01,.01,.01,rep(.00,12))
c9 <- c(.01,.01,.01,.01,rep(.00,12))
c10 <- runif(16,.3,.6)
test.mat2 <- cbind(c6,c7,c8,c9,c10)
csums2 <- colSums(test.mat2)
csums2
      c6       c7       c8       c9      c10 
7.198180 7.449324 0.040000 0.040000 8.172110
```

A sample of the result would look like the following:

```
result <- matrix(c(2,0,3,4),nrow=2,byrow=T)
result
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    0
[2,]    3    4
```

where row 1 records that column 2's sum is less than .1, and row two records that columns 3 and 4 in the next data frame in the list had sums less than .1. My actual data is a list with a few thousand data frames in it, and the result data frame continues on for total length of my list. I plan on embedding this conditional statement inside a loop to go through each list element.

Comment: The main thing you need is `which(csums<0.1)`.  I'll post a complete answer in a minute.

Comment: When calling RNG's you should start your scripts with a call to `set.seed()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that takes as input the list of matrices `test.mat1` and `test.mat2` that you provided:

```
my_list <- list(test.mat1, test.mat2)

# For each data frame in the list, compute the column sums
# and return the indices of the columns for which the sum < 0.1
res <- lapply(my_list, function(x) {
  which(colSums(x) < 0.1)
})

# Get the number of columns for each element of the list
len <- lengths(res)
if(any(len == 0)) { # in case you have no values < 0.1, put a 0
  res[which(len == 0)] <- 0
}

# Get your result:
result <- do.call("rbind", res)

# replace duplicated values by 0:
result[t(apply(result, 1, duplicated))] <- 0
```

Comment: When I use my actual data in place of the sample list, I get an error reading "Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, which(len == 0), value = 0) : recursive indexing failed at level 2". The only difference between my actual list and the sample on is that my actual list is a list of data frames rather than matrices. Could this be causing the issue? Also, I do need the index to be zero rather than repeated. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I edited my answer (two last lines) to replaced repeated values by 0. However, I cannot reproduce your error when converting test.mat1 and test.mat2 as data frames. Do you have more information about the problem?

Comment: It works when I test specific parts of my list (e.g., 10 elements out of 2916), but not the whole thing. Could the problem come from the fact that some list elements don't have any column sums that meet the condition? I want it to read 0 in that case, but that's the only difference between list elements that I can identify.

Comment: I found the problem. It happened when more than 1 data frame didn't meet the condition. I edited my answer (`res[which(len == 0)]` replaces `res[[which(len == 0)]]`). Hope this will work!

Answer (score 1):

Example data:

```
set.seed(1234)
df1 <- data.frame(
    c1 = runif(16,.3,.6),
    c2 = c(.01,.01,.01,.01,rep(.00,12)),
    c3 = runif(16,.3,.6),
    c4 = runif(16,.3,.6),
    c5 = runif(16,.3,.6)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
    c6  = runif(16,.3,.6),
    c7  = runif(16,.3,.6),
    c8  = c(.01,.01,.01,.01,rep(.00,12)),
    c9  = c(.01,.01,.01,.01,rep(.00,12)),
    c10 = runif(16,.3,.6)
)
```

Create a vector of the dataframe names to use

```
vec_of_df_names <- c("df1", "df2")
```

Loop over dataframes:

```
res_mat <- matrix(0, nrow=2, ncol=5)
for(i in seq_along(vec_of_df_names)) {
    res <- which(colSums(get(vec_of_df_names[i])) < 0.1)
    if(length(res)>0) res_mat[i, seq_along(res)] <- res
}
res_mat
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.